# How to allow other people test my react native app on their iPhone and Android devices?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, testing

I'm a web developer and just new to the mobile world, I wonder how I can allow another people to test my app on their device remotely?
For example, on the web app, I will create a staging environment (stg.example.com) and then they can easily test it from everywhere. But I can't found the same way for mobile app (react native). I can install the app to my phone through a capable, but I can't do it on my customer phone :sad:

Do I must publish it to App Store/CH Play first and then they can install and test it? It seems a bad idea :sad:

I really appreciate any advice,
Thanks!

Comment: cd android and ./gredlew assembleRelease . So generate  first release apk and then you can test on any device (android).

Answer (score 1):

1-You can use Expo CLI where you can send the QR Code to your other team members and they can easily check your app with EXPO APP by using the QR Code.

2-If you are using react-native CLI then there is only one way to send your android app to your other team members or friends and that is to generate a signed apk. Read here how to generate signed apk : https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

Once you get the apk you can send it to anyone through google drive or any other free cloud storage or through Bluetooth.

For IOS it's quite difficult you need to have an Apple account to generate ipa (iOS App Store Package). See this it will help you [How to share a compiled iOS app ipa with your users for testing](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/05/14/how-to-share-ios-app-ipa-with-users-for-testing-using-dropbox-or-your-website/)

Comment: Thank you, I looked on Expo sdk, it really nice for instant preview the app, but of course it has many cons, especially I can't access native code... It seems that Expo isn't a good choice for business app that may growth big in the future. Maybe I should use `testflight` and `GooglePlay alpha testing` to allow our QA test the app even the workflow take amount time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Upload it to playstore/ app store is not a bad idea, e.g. you can do a closed beta test there. Another option is when your customer activate *unknown sources* on there device they can install the apps directly.

Comment: But does it wasted time because on the development cycle the app will be updated frequently, and each time I must re-build the app and publish it to App Store and then our customer must update it on their phone, does it?

Comment: I looked on expo sdk, it really nice for instant preview the app, but of course it has many cons, especially I can't access native code T_T

Comment: that's true, it takes time.. maybe not the right approach for you. but on the other hand, you shouldn't  publish a lot of new features in a short time period and ask for ongoning testing. your customers will get tired of it very soon... btw, I don't know how your customers don't have to update or reinstall the app when you add new features. at least not if it should be an app on their mobile devices and not just a website..

Comment: Yes, maybe that approach is wrong for mobile app, I familiar with `agile` approach that mean our customer will join to development cycle very soon to allow them make a lot of decision to the app before it was released, example maybe a early change request. And our customer also have some testers (web testers, lol) so they want to test the app as soon as possible, and you know, when they testing a lot of bug will be produced, and I must fix and deploy it as soon as possible, too. Maybe I must change the development approach when moving to app development...

Comment: `btw, I don't know how your customers don't have to update or reinstall the app when you add new features`. Sorry, I don't mean our customer can't update/reinstall the app, I just think this approach seems wasted a lot of time T_T Anyway, thank you so much for your advice :D